# Rails render json displaying on screen

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, ajax

I have a Rails 5.1 app using Webpacker, jQuery 3. I'm trying to render json back to the browser after making an Ajax post. Here's my controller:

```
def create
  @giver = Giver.new(giver_params)
  return unless @giver.valid?
  if @giver.save
    render json: { location: 'url' }, status: :ok
  end
end
```

Here's my javascript (I have a route that directs /give to the controller's create method):

```
  $form.get(0).submit();

  var jqxhr = $.ajax({
      url: '/give',
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: $form.serialize()
    })
    .done(function() {
      console.log(jqxhr['responseText']);
      $('#new-gift').hide(function() {
        $('#confirm-gift').show();
      });
      return false;
    })
    .fail(function() {
    })
    .always(function() {
    });
}
```

I've done this so many times without any trouble, but for some reason it's now rendering

```
{"location":"url"}
```

on the screen, not performing any of the functions (hiding/showing divs) in the `.done` call. It saves everything to the db just fine, as well. I figured the `return false;` in the `.done` section would do the trick, but it doesn't. Any ideas? I can't see any other questions that address this - if they are out there, please direct me to the answer. Thank you.

```
.container.active-div#new-gift
  = form_for @giver, url: give_path, remote: true, html: { id: "payment-form" } do |f|
    %h3 Your Information
      .panel-body
        .row
          .col-md-6
            = f.text_field :first_name, class: "form-control", placeholder: "First Name"
            %br/
          .col-md-6
            = f.text_field :last_name, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Last Name"
            %br/          
    .row
      .col-md-12.text-center
        %br/
        = button_tag "Donate", class: "btn btn-primary btn-lg submit", style: "width: 150px; margin-bottom: 50px;"
```

Comment: What were you expecting back? From what I can see what you are passing to the `render` function is just a hash with `location` as key and `url` as the value which is what exactly you are getting back in the frontend.

Comment: Yes, I am getting back the correct json, but I am trying to prevent it from rendering on the screen. I want to hide and show div tags in my ajax method, but that functionality is being ignored, and it's simply displaying the json on the screen. I should also say I have two partials in my view: the first is a form, the second is confirmation of everything entered. Once the user submits the form, I want to hide the form (which is what I'm trying to do in the javascript) and display the confirmation, with a final submit button, which will finalize the transaction and redirect to a thank you page.

Comment: Can you include your html code?

Comment: Sure, I added a snippet of the form above in the body - I removed several of the form components, but kept the form and button tags, because that should provide any telling information, if it's there.

Comment: I'm also doing some other Javascript related to Stripe above the ajax call, so I added the `form.get(0).submit();` call so you can see how I'm submitting the form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are triggering a manual `ajax` form submission,  `remote: true` is not required in the form. Just remove `remote: true` from the form and prevent the form submission event once it is triggered. Then, the code will look like

```
 $("#payment-form").submit(function(event){
   var jqxhr = $.ajax({
      url: '/give',
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: $form.serialize()
    })
    .done(function() {
       console.log(jqxhr['responseText']);
       $('#new-gift').hide(function() {
         $('#confirm-gift').show();
       });
    });
    .fail(function() {
    })
    .always(function() {
    });
    event.preventDefault();
 });
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks so much! It turns out I was posting the form an extra time, and adding the preventDefault() did the trick. Can't believe I completely missed that!